# Safari and wrong svg viewBox change

Tags: jquery, css, svg, safari

In short words, I got a problem with an svg that i need to change the viewBox with jquery during scroll because the logo do a "crop" (opacity 0 of a ) and it moves in the left of the menu, all during scroll of the content.

I've tested it in Windows (Chrome, Firefox and Edge) and in Mac (Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari), only in Safari the viewBox maintain after the scroll, so the logo it's bigger than it needs, but if I read the code the viewBox of the svg has changed and if i change the size of the container of the logo it goes o the right size.

Anyone else that has encountered this problem? Tips?

Comment: Please include an [MCVE] in your question.

Comment: If you've found a webkit bug you can report it [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi)

Comment: No needing for wxample, this is the server http://vps113772.ovh.net/ergologiche